# Form - update "reset" button to new data

Tags: javascript, forms, mootools, reset

I'm using mootools in 1 of my projects. I'm working on easy to be customised menu based on sortables.

So here's the issue - I've got the form which contains menu node informations. Form is updated with JS whenever user chooses different node (form is populated with new data). Problem is that "reset" button obviously "remembers" the initial data, so whenever user clicks it, it loads initial data form.

Is there anyway to update the "default" form status, whenever i load new data? (ofc i could write piece of code which do whatever i need, but if there is some simplier solution which allows default "reset" button to work with new data would be much less work to use it :))

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

i cant think of anything else except getting a new source through ajax with data prepopulated and replace the innerhtml hence replacing the form itself.

Comment: Was thinking the same so far - grab all children of old "form" tag, insert them into new form and replace old form tag. Will "reset" button work as intended then?

Comment: Tried this:

    var oldFormChildren = $('editNodeForm').getChildren();
    var newForm = new Element('form', {
      'id': 'editNodeForm',
      'method':'post',
      'action':'#'
    }).adopt(oldFormChildren).replaces($('editNodeForm'));

Doesn't seem to work tho. Any ideas?

Comment: So far worked it around - added variable which remember current node data and populate form whenever reset is pressed. But still would appreciate suggestion of better solutions

Comment: if you only have to save the old form data, why not do $('editNodeForm').toQueryString() and save in a simple string?  This string can even be ajaxed easily to server and server understands it well too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like `toQueryString` to serialize the form and then reverse it based upon the mootools-more's `String.parseQueryString()`:

```
(function() {

Element.implement({

    saveFormState: function() {
        if (this.get('tag') !== 'form')
            return;
        this.store("defaults", this.toQueryString());
    },

    restoreFormState: function() {
        if (this.get('tag') !== 'form')
            return;
        var vals = this.retrieve("defaults");
        if (!vals.length)
            return;

        var self = this;
        Object.each(vals.parseQueryString(vals), function(value, key) {
            var el = self.getElement("[name=" + key + "]");
            el && el.set('value', value);
        });
    }
});

})();

var f = document.id('f');

// save default
f.saveFormState();

document.getElement("button").addEvent("click", f.restoreFormState.bind(f));
```

this ough to cover most cases and you can always save a new defaults state. need to test it somewhat with radios and suchlike, though.

here's a basic fiddle with a save/restore: http://jsfiddle.net/UWTUJ/1/

relevant docs: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/String.QueryString (more) and http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:toQueryString (core)

implied reliance on name attributes on all form elements you want to save/restore.

I have previously created more complex save/restore states that even return field CSS class names, validation messages, etc.